# Filtering PDF files that contain given keyword

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, itext

I am trying to make a `listBox` that will display PDF files that contain given keyword in `textBox`.
I am using iTextSharp 7. All files are loaded into `listBox` as full path strings.
This is what I've done so far:

Function for finding the given keyword:

```
private int ReadPdfFile(string fileName, String searthText)
{
    int indicator = 0; 

    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);
        {
            for (int page = 1; page <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); page++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();

                string currentPageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfDocument.GetPage(page), strategy);

                if (currentPageText.Contains(searthText))
                {
                    indicator++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return indicator;
}
```

And the `textBox` code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox2.Items.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (ReadPdfFile(items[i].ToString(), textBox1.Text)>0)
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(items[i]);
        }
    }          
}
```

But when I try to type anything in textbox I get the following exception at `PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);`

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'Common.Logging, Version=3.4.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.'

Any suggestions?
Am I even going in the right direction?

Comment: [IText7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/) has some dependencies, one of which is [Common.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Common.Logging/). I suggest to re-install the NuGet Package. (Btw, the search on the full list of PDF files on each `TextChanged` event will cause other problems, later, IMO). (Btw2, I'ld check out that AGPL licence twice)

Comment: I will try to figure it out!
Thank you for your concern, but I am just learning, it's not like I can or plan on making anything pratical, my knowledge is lacking to say at least, complete noob in this area...

Comment: Was my answer helpful for you?

Comment: It solved that problem!
I have accepted your answer. But as @Jimi said, search on the full list of PDF files on each TextChanged event will cause other problems.
It freezes if i type in more than few letters, so I need to find a way to deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the file Common.Logging.dll is in the bin directory of your project.If not

Try this in visual studio in package manager console type this.

```
PM> Install-Package Common.Logging
```